Two sided plane geometry
When adding a simple plane to the scene, then export it to any file format (fbx, glb, etc), naturally, it will create 2 triangles, which will be consist of 4 unique vertexes, and 6 unique vertex indexes.
Since most engines/apps do back(or front) face culling, then plane will not be visible from the opposite side.
This is all good and expected.
Is there a way in Blender, to add a plane, and do some magic, so the plane will continue to have 4 unique vertexes, but forms 2-2 triangles on each side, with (probably) 12 unique vertex index data?
I am aware of how to make two sided materials on a plane in Blender, but what I am after is generating this two sided plane geometry.
Thanks!

I'm surprised to find that the bMesh engine apparently doesn't seem to support this. All my attempts ended um removing one of the faces, at least through the UI. Not sure if one could possibly force it through Python.

I have never been able to create something like this in Blender, whenever I tried something like that like putting two planes in the same space and merge the 8 vertices, it is not possible to make 4 vertices of them while keeping two separate planes. However I have had models from CAD software imported into Blender where this was the case, so somehow these can exist in Blender even though you cannot create them. For a possible Python method I'm unfortunately not qualified.

You would have to create 2 different planes then and move them slightly apart to avoid overlapping geometry for this to work absolutely everywhere. There is no universal way for any possible other software to treat geometry as double sided.
Inside Blender you can use Backfacing output of Geometry node to choose how back faces should be shaded:

Note that you would sometimes have to flip some other properties like IOR for some shaders for them to behave as expected when using this.
It is pretty much expected you would do something similar in other software if you want back faces to be displayed(enable or disable some setting or somehow take care of it in shaders). The concept of back faces is definitely not unique to Blender and there are usually ways to deal with them in other software, but how you do that has nothing to do with Blender so that's outside the scope of Blender Stack Exchange.

This setup creates a material that's different for the two sides of the plane, but the question states a two-sided material is not what is desired: "I am aware of how to make two sided materials on a plane in Blender, but what I am after is generating this two sided plane geometry."

I added it as the second part, which I thought might be relevant for whoever finds this in the future, but the real answer is that if one wants double sided geometry that would work in ANY unspecified third party software with ANY format, there is no standard universally accepted and supported way to do that and the only workaround would be to actually have double geometry. This is true as far as I know.

I don't know... Maybe this is not a question I should have answered at all... Do you know anything about any existing standards in various formats and software that would be popular for dealing with this somehow storing any additional data within the geometry itself? As far as I know, there are none and it's pretty much universally accepted, this should be done in shaders and nothing like double vertices or faces are ever stored for this - that would be inefficient. Surface is defined, then it's up to shaders how it's displayed.

The thing is, doing this in a shader will not help if someone is planning to export it in FBX or anything, because the Geometry node's Backfacing will not be exported. I think double geometry is inefficient, too and if someone would model things with manifold geometry there will be no need to have double-sided materials anyway. I've seen discussions where people claim (some? all?) game engines would render double geometry faster than double sided shaders, no idea if this is true. But whatever, Blender cannot natively do that, at least not with merging vertices.

It does indeed make sense. I have no idea if that's the case in all possible software though... Who knows?..

@MartynasŽiemys thanks for the input, but please focus less on the export format. In fact the export file format itself is unaware of how the geometry was composed inside Blender. It juts holds the vertex and vertex index data. The sole purpose of the vertex index data is exactly that: reuse existing vertexes when forming triangles. In my case i wish to have 2 triangles on each side, sharing the 4 vertexes. So in my view, it is very much in the scope of Blender itself.

@GordonBrinkmann I can confirm that it is not possible in Blender. I did an experiment: created to opposing planes. Joined them to one mesh. Then in Edit mode, i merged the 8 vertexes 2 by 2, and the second plane disappeared. Make your response an answer please, so i can mark it as solution.

@Avi How is my comment a solution? It's not solving anything. I do not know a way of doing this, but I have had meshes from other software which had exactly that: two planes built from the same four vertices. So I'm wondering if Blender "accepts" this kind of geometry, shouldn't there be some way of replicating this in Blender? Because no matter the file format, once imported into Blender, it is a Blender mesh after all. You can write answers to your own questions by the way, if you're content with "not possible" as answer feel free to post and accept it.

@GordonBrinkmann okay i took this "But whatever, Blender cannot natively do that, at least not with merging vertices" as a confident statement that Blender can't do it
